# Add 5 minutes to date in bash

Tags: command-line, date, timestamps

I've seen that the "date" command can do powerful manipulation of timestamps, but I'm not quite getting it to work right.  Can anyone help explain the output below, and suggest how I could get the expected result of "May 03, 2018 23:38"

```
$ date -d "May  3, 2018 23:33 + 5 minutes" "+%b %d, %Y %H:%M"
May 03, 2018 13:34
```

Answer (score 2):

After playing around with it a bit more, I think I found the solution.  I needed to add the timezone and change the syntax slightly:

```
$ date -d "May  3, 2018 23:33 CDT +5 min" "+%b %d, %Y %H:%M %Z"
May 03, 2018 23:38 CDT
```